# TypedQuery remove data from getResultList()

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have data stored in the database, it looks more or less like this

```
[
  {
    "accountNumber": "00000123,0000124",
    "fullName": "CUSTOMER XXX"
  },
  {
    "accountNumber": "00000128",
    "fullName": "CUSTOMER AAA"
  }
]
```

here I add code to retrieve data with condition using ***like***

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ModelEntity> query = builder.createQuery(ModelEntity.class);
        Root<ModelEntity> root = query.from(ModelEntity.class);
        
        List<Predicate> listWhere = new ArrayList<>();

        if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(param.getAccountNumber())){

            // it's over here
            listWhere.add(builder.like(root.get('accountNumber'), '%'+param.getAccountNumber()+'%'));
        }

        TypedQuery<ModelEntity> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query
                .where(listWhere.toArray(new Predicate[] {}))
                .orderBy(builder.desc(root.get('createdDate')))
        );
```

because the condition uses ***like***, then there is a possibility if the accountNumber parameter that is sent is this = **"0000012"**, both data will be taken, therefore I added a re-filter to remove data that does not match the sent param

```
        // filter accountNumbers
        if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(param.getAccountNumber()) && typedQuery.getResultList().size() > 0){
            List<ModelEntity> removeData = new ArrayList<>();
            typedQuery.getResultList().forEach(data->{
                List<String> accountNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
                
                if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(data.getAccountNumber())) {
                    accountNumbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(data.getAccountNumber().split(",")));   // accountNumber value = "00000123,0000124"
                }
                
                if(!accountNumbers.isEmpty() && !accountNumbers.contains(param.getAccountNumber())) {
                    removeData.add(data);
                }
            });
            
            if(!removeData.isEmpty()) {
                typedQuery.getResultList().removeAll(removeData);
            }
        }

        Integer total = typedQuery.getResultList().size();
        List<ModelEntity> result = typedQuery
                .setMaxResults(paging.getRowPerPage())                          // rowPerPage = 10
                .setFirstResult(paging.getRowPerPage() * (paging.getPage()-1))  // page = 1
                .getResultList();
```

the problem is this code doesn't work `typedQuery.getResultList().removeAll(removeData);` , the data attached is still size 2, but the expectation is 0. is there something wrong?, please help

Comment: Your data violates first normal form. Strongly consider reviewing your DB model instead of writing tricky code